# How to do this in Regex.Replace?

Tags: python, regex

I have a very basic query. I am having my blast results in tabular format. My current results look like

[image]

I want to edit my results in column2 to get output like as mentioned below in

> 6561412 (number followed by gi before gb)>
>
> 752455730 (number followed by gi before gb)
>
> 30348501 (number followed by gi before gb)

Our online server provide regex option as shown in picture[image]

example provided by server [image]

This tool uses Python regular expressions with the re.sub() function. More information about Python regular expressions can be found here:

Looking forward to your kind help
Regards

Comment: You want this using what language?

Comment: Thanks Sir I have edited my question to be more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Column: `Column: 2`
Find Regex: `gi\|(.*?)\|gb.*`
Replacement: `\1`

Comment: Thanks Sir I have edited my question to be more precise

Comment: @AliZohaib - I have edited the answer. Check if it works.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I did a little amendment and it worked 

Find Regex:    .*?\|(.*?)\|.*?\|(.*?)\|.*
Replacement:   \1

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on regex:

```
import re

data = "gi|6561412|gb|AF191073.1|AF191073_Stealth_virus_1_clone_3B43,_genomic_sequence"

match = re.match(r".*?\|([^|]+)", data)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))  # 6561412
```

But why bother with regex when you can do simple a limited split at a much lower cost:

```
data = "gi|6561412|gb|AF191073.1|AF191073_Stealth_virus_1_clone_3B43,_genomic_sequence"

tokenized_data = data.split("|", 2)
if len(tokenized_data) >= 1:
    print(tokenized_data[1])  # 6561412
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, actually our online server has just regex option.

Comment: @AliZohaib - `str.split()` is native part of Python - if Python is working, `str.split()` will work too.

Comment: Thanks Sir I have edited my question to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Everyone, the below-mentioned answer worked

Find Regex: `.*?\|(.*?)\|.*?\|(.*?)\|.*`

Replacement: `\1`